# How to add a string to each entries in a DropDownListFor with asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, dropdown

I'm working on a project about task management. I have created a page to create a new task and I'm trying to add a Dropdown populated with financial periods (e.g "2018-2019", "2021-2022").

What I've tried so far is creating the SelectList with simple years (from 2018 to 2050), I added the correct format in the main view but I can't use the same thing in  my DropDownListFor. Here's what I have now :

Model :

```cs
// List with years from 2018 to 2050
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TaskPeriods =
              new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(2018, (2050 - 2018) + 1));
// Selected period
 public int TaskPeriod { get; set; }
```

Main View (outputs in the right format):

```
@foreach(var items in Model)
{
     <tr>
          <td>@items.TaskPeriod-@(items.TaskPeriod + 1)</td>
     </tr>
```

Create View (dropdown only outputs list of years, i'd like it to show years in the same format as the main view)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewTask", "Task", FormMethod.Post))
{
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Financial Period</label><br/>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.TaskPeriod, new SelectList(Model.TaskPeriods, "Value", "Text"))
    </div>
}
```

Output on main view has the "year - year+1" format which is correct but I couldn't find a way to display the same result in my dropdown (only shows "year" format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the Text string before binding with `DropDownListFor`

```
    @{
      var newSource = Model.TaskPeriods.Select(m => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = m.Text.ToString(),
          Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}",  m.Text.ToString(),Convert.ToInt32(m.Text)+1)
      }); 
      SelectList finalSource = new SelectList(newSource, "Value ", "Text");
     }
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Financial Period</label><br/>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.TaskPeriods, finalSource)
    </div>
```

In this case, your value is an original value (`2018`) but the text looks like `2018-2019`
if you want to change the value then modify the value parameter similarly.

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsHkCA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't know it was possible to declare Value and Text the way you did.